# how to add xml namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, api, namespaces

This feed (snippit of it) needs to look exactly like this:

```
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
```

what do I add to this C# code to add that extra xmlns, xsi junk:

```
writer.WriteStartDocument();
writer.WriteStartElement("AmazonEnvelope");
```

this feed is rejected without it--

Comment: You haven't mentioned which programming language you're using. One assumes C# because WriteStartDocument is a method on XmlWriter, but that's not a guarantee.

Comment: It says "C#" in the middle of the line just below the XML fragment.....

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
writer.WriteStartElement("AmazonEnvelope");
writer.WriteAttributeString(
  "xmlns", "xsi", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
writer.WriteAttributeString(
  "xsi", "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", null, "amzn-envelope.xsd");
...
writer.WriteEndElement();
```

Comment: wow, i learn so much here!! I'm moving along now... amazon accepted the feed... touchy api!!

Answer (score 5):

Is .NET 3.5 an option?

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

string s = new XElement("AmazonEnvelope",
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", ns),
    new XAttribute(ns + "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "amzn-envelope.xsd")
).ToString();
```

---

or with `XmlWriter`:

```
const string ns = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
writer.WriteStartDocument();
writer.WriteStartElement("AmazonEnvelope");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", "", ns);
writer.WriteAttributeString("xsi", "noNamespaceSchemaLocation",
      ns, "mzn-envelope.xsd");
writer.WriteEndDocument();
```