# XML Serialization + Namespaces (C#)

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, namespaces

I need to generate something like this:

```
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
...
</Header>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

I was trying something like this but it's not fully correctly:

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces nms = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        nms.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        nms.Add("noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "amzn-envelope.xsd");



        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLAmazonEnvelope));
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path);

        serializer.Serialize(writer, objectToSave,nms);
        writer.Close();
```

And result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsi:AmazonEnvelope xmlns:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsi:Header>
...
</xsi:Header>
</xsi:AmazonEnvelope>
```

And this is not exactly what I want.
Any ideas, what should be done differently?

Comment: `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd"` isn't a namespace declaration. You'll have to add an attribute `noNamespaceShcemaLocation` in the `xsi` namespace to the `AmazonEnvelope` element, but I can't really see a straightforward way to do it in the documentation unless you have access to the source of `XMLAmazonEnvelope`. In that case you could add a field/property to that class annotated with `[XmlAttribute]` with the name `noNamespaceSchemaLocation` and the value you want.

Comment: Or maybe it's possible with access to the source by using `XmlAttributeOverrides`, but I've no idea exactly how that API works.

Comment: XmlAttribute is only allow for fields, properties, indexes and I have:

Comment: [XmlRoot(ElementName = "AmazonEnvelope", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="noNamespaceSchemaLocation")]
    public class XMLAmazonEnvelope
    {
        private ObservableCollection<XMLMessage> _Messages = new ObservableCollection<XMLMessage>(); 

        [XmlElement(ElementName="Header")]
        public XMLHeader Header{get;set;} ....

Comment: So attach the `[XmlAttribute(AttributeName="noNamespaceSchemaLocation")]` to a string field with the value `"amzn-envelope.xsd"`. (And use the correct namespace in the attribute.)

Comment: `[XmlRoot(ElementName = "AmazonEnvelope", Namespace = "http://w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]` is probably also wrong. `AmazonEnvelope` isn't a XML Schema element. Maybe you should brush up on what XML namespaces are first.

Comment: In this link here that issue is already solved:

[how to add xml namespaces (Amazon envelope][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928126/how-to-add-xml-namespces

Answer (score 0):

Question already solved here:

[How to add xml namespaces (Amazon Envelope)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928126/how-to-add-xml-namespces)